# Angular $scope object not updating in view

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-scope

I have a large object of products that is filtered based on categories. When a filter is selected, the `getAllProducts()` function I have is called with that filter. This function also sets the `$scope.products` which I have an `ng-repeat` for in an `<li>` in my view.

With each category selected, I am console logging the length of the returned products object, and see that the object correctly updates, but my view does not change. Does anyone see what's wrong here?

view:

```
  <li ng-repeat="product in products track by $index">
      <img ng-model="category" class="{{product.custom.category_code}}" src="/img/product-all/{{product.custom.sku}}PF1.png">
      <p class="name">{{product.custom.name1}}</p>
      <p class="price">{{product.price}}</p>
  </li>

  <li class='has-sub first-menu'><a href='/scroll'><span>Filter By Category:</span></a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="cat in filterCategory">
           <a href='/scroll' data-category="all" ng-click="setFilter('category', cat)">
              <span>{{cat}}</span>
           </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='has-sub first-menu'><a href='/scroll'><span>Filter By Color:</span></a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="color in filterColor">
           <a href='/scroll' data-category="all" ng-click="setFilter('color', color)">
              <span>{{color}}</span>
           </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li class='has-sub first-menu'><a href='/scroll'><span>Filter By Season:</span></a>
     <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="season in filterSeason">
           <a href='/scroll' data-category="all" ng-click="setFilter('season', season)">
              <span>{{season}}</span>
           </a>
        </li>
     </ul>
  </li>
```

controller:

```
    $scope.setFilter = function(type, filter){
        type = type;
        filter = filter;
        getProducts(type, filter);
    }
    var getProducts = function(type, filter){
        productFactory.getAllProducts()
            .then(function(){
                $timeout( function(){
                    var allProducts = productFactory.products;
                    var filterProducts;
                    switch (type){
                        case "category":
                            filterProducts = $filter('filter')(allProducts, {custom:{category_code:filter}});
                            break;
                        case "color":
                            filterProducts = $filter('filter')(allProducts, {custom:{color_code:filter}});
                            break;
                        case "season":
                            filterProducts = $filter('filter')(allProducts, {custom:{season:filter}});
                            break;
                        default:
                            filterProducts = productFactory.products;
                    }
                    $scope.products = _.uniq(filterProducts, function(p){ return p.custom.sku; });
                    console.log($scope.products.length);
                }, 700);
            });
    }
```

factory:

```
var getAllProducts = function(){
        return $http.get('/api/scroll?page='+pageNumber)
            .then(function(response) {
                angular.extend(products,response);
                for (var i = products.data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    productsData.push(products.data.results[i]);
                };
                while (pageNumber <= products.data.pages){
                    getAllProducts();
                    pageNumber++;
                }
                for (var i = productsData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                    if (filterCategory.indexOf(productsData[i].custom.category_code) == -1) {
                        filterCategory.push(productsData[i].custom.category_code);
                    };
                    if (filterColor.indexOf(productsData[i].custom.color_code) == -1) {
                        filterColor.push(productsData[i].custom.color_code);
                        // $filter('orderBy')(filterColor, '+');
                    };
                    if (filterSeason.indexOf(productsData[i].custom.season) == -1) {
                        filterSeason.push(productsData[i].custom.season);
                    };
                };
                var deferred = $q.defer();
                deferred.resolve(response);
                products = productsData;
                return deferred.promise;

            });
    };
```

Comment: could you add your `getAllProducts` factory method code?

Comment: Did you try removing the `track by $index`?

Comment: @bumpy yup, didn't change anything

Comment: @PankajParkar just added

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you missed to return data from service method, it should return the formatted data. No need of creating a promise again while you have already using `$http` which is returning promise.

Then inside your controller `getAllProducts().then` functions parameter will have data in it which have returned from the service method.

**Factory**

```
var getAllProducts = function() {
    return $http.get('/api/scroll?page=' + pageNumber)
    .then(function(response) {
      angular.extend(products, response);
      for (var i = products.data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        productsData.push(products.data.results[i]);
      };
      while (pageNumber <= products.data.pages) {
        getAllProducts();
        pageNumber++;
      }
      for (var i = productsData.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (filterCategory.indexOf(productsData[i].custom.category_code) == -1) {
          filterCategory.push(productsData[i].custom.category_code);
        };
        if (filterColor.indexOf(productsData[i].custom.color_code) == -1) {
          filterColor.push(productsData[i].custom.color_code);
          // $filter('orderBy')(filterColor, '+');
        };
        if (filterSeason.indexOf(productsData[i].custom.season) == -1) {
          filterSeason.push(productsData[i].custom.season);
        };
      };
      return productsData; //return data from here

    });
};
```

**Controller**

```
var getProducts = function(type, filter) {
  productFactory.getAllProducts()
  .then(function(products) { //<--added data parameter here
    var allProducts = products; //<--assigned data to all products
    var filterProducts;
    switch (type) {
      case "category":
        filterProducts = $filter('filter')(allProducts, {
          custom: {category_code: filter}
        });
        break;
      case "color":
        filterProducts = $filter('filter')(allProducts, {
          custom: {color_code: filter}
        });
        break;
      case "season":
        filterProducts = $filter('filter')(allProducts, {
          custom: {season: filter}
        });
        break;
      default:
        filterProducts = productFactory.products;
    }
    $scope.products = _.uniq(filterProducts, function(p) {
      return p.custom.sku;
    });
    console.log($scope.products.length);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Pankaj, but this is still not updating my view. The functions are working as they did before, but again, my view is not responding as expected.